# Gram Mav'ir on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, hefsek-interruption, leniencies, fire-burning

I heard once that the poskim permit "gram mav'ir" on yom tov l'tzrich gadol. For example if someone wants to use a platta (hot plate) that they forgot to plug in they may plug it in with a Shabbos clock that will later turn on the hot plate. Where does it say that gram mav'ir is permitted on yom tov? Who were/are the poskim that discuss this?

Comment: That latter psak assumes the only problem with plugging in an electric device is maavir. There could be many other issues as well, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12604/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16601/759

Comment: @Double AA let's address the point of "boneh" since there is a nice chiddush in this. Boneh on Yom Tov might be muter completely -- See Tosfos Shabbos (95a). L'maseh he comes out that it's still ossur (Boneh on Yom Tov) because of "ovdeh d'chol." Therefore some want to say (as I've heard from poskim) that ovdeh d'chol is shayach when you would build an entire binyan. However the chiddush of the Chazzon Ish that electricity is boneh as it is is difficult to understand. Therefore in an ofen like this (working with electricity) even Tosfos wouldn't call it "ovdeh d'chol."

Comment: @Yehoshua - Especially in light of the multiple alternative rationales for forbidding electricity use, I would not rely on that l'halachah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nitey Gavriel (Hilchos Yom Tov Cheleck Aleph, end of Chapter 20)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46542&st=&pgnum=160) quotes many poskim permitting "gram m'avir" on Yom Tov; see footnote 42 there.